# Decoding JSON stream where some values are needed before others

Tags: haskell, aeson, haskell-pipes

Let us say we have a JSON object like this (with base64 encoded bytestring):

```
TaggedImage = TaggedImage {  id :: Text, image :: ByteString }
```

Now, we want to receive `image` from a source, and store it in a location using the information in `id` tag. So, what that means is that `id` must be parsed ahead of time (to determine location for the image) while `image` is parsed in streaming fashion. Is this straight-forward to do?

I am planning to use `pipes-aeson`, `aws` (for `S3` storage) and `pipes` to do streaming decoding from `Websocket` producer with a `S3` bucket as the consumer (which can't be created until we parse the `id` to determine the location of `S3` bucket). Looking at [`decoded`](https://s3.amazonaws.com/haddock.stackage.org/lts-6.0/pipes-aeson-0.4.1.6/Pipes-Aeson.html) method, I can't figure out if I could indeed do what I asked above. This is my first attempt at streaming in JSON and pipes. So, help will be very much appreciated.

A simple example with read and write to the filesystem will also do as stand-in for `Websocket producer` and `S3 consumer`.

**Addendum**

Since JSON key-value pairs are  unordered according to [RFC](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159.txt) while the arrays are ordered, `image` data might come before `id`, it seems, for the data type I defined above. So, it might also help to change it to JSON array (a tuple in Haskell which `aeson` TH derivation seems to convert to ordered array). Please feel free to change the data type definition if need be, to impose ordering for decoding. For example, the data type might be changed to:

```
TaggedImage = TaggedImage (Text,ByteString)
```

Comment: I assume you want to stream the image directly to disk?

Comment: @ErikR, yep, that should be fine for example purposes. Disk location depends on id.

Comment: I don't think `decoded` can stream directly to disk. Each parsed top-level JSON value is parsed in it's entirety before its given to you.

Comment: @ErikR, yep, `decoded` signature shows the same thing. Would a manual parser work instead of `decoded`? Like make a stream out of bytestring and pass it directly to `pipes` after manually parsing `id` in ordered JSON array? Not sure if `aeson` allows for that.

Comment: You would have to write your own JSON parser. It would be easier to implement a simple line-oriented protocol with two commands: `Id ...` and `chunk ...`. When you see an `id ...` line it begins a new file. When you see a `chunk ...` line it means to write that (base64) encoded chunk to the current file. Perhaps an empty `chunk` line means end of file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you won’t be able to reuse the `pipes-aeson` library because it doesn't provide a way to stream over a nested field of a decoded JSON record nor is there any support for cursor-like navigation of the struct.  That means that you will need to parse the skeleton of the JSON record by hand.

Also, some work needs to be done to wrap the `base64-bytestring` in a `pipes`-like API with this type:

```
-- Convert a base64-encoded stream to a raw byte stream
decodeBase64
    :: Producer ByteString m r
    -- ^ Base64-encoded bytes
    -> Producer ByteString m (Either SomeException (Producer ByteString m r)) 
    -- ^ Raw bytes
```

Note that the result returns a `Producer` for the remainder of the byte string (i.e. everything after the base64-encoded bytes) if the decoding completes successfully.  This lets you resume parsing where the image bytes end.

However, assuming that you have a `decodeBase64` function, then the rough outline of how the code would work is that you’d have three parts:

- Parse the prefix of the record before the image bytes using a `binary` parser adapted to `pipes`
- Use the `decodeBase64` function to stream the decoded image bytes
- Parse the suffix of the record after the image bytes also using a `binary` parser adapted to `pipes`

In other words, the types and implementation would look roughly like this:

```
-- This would match the "{ 'id' : 'foo', 'image' : '" prefix of the JSON record
skipPrefix :: Data.Binary.Get ()

skipPrefix’ :: Monad m => Producer ByteString m r -> m (Either DecodingError (Producer ByteString m r))
skipPrefix’ = execStateT (Pipes.Binary.decodeGet skipPrefix)

— This would match the "' }" suffix of the JSON record
skipSuffix :: Data.Binary.Get ()

skipSuffix’ :: Monad m => Producer ByteString m r -> m (Either DecodingError (Producer ByteString m r))
skipSuffix’ = execStateT (Pipes.Binary.decodeGet skipSuffix)

streamImage
    ::  Monad m
    =>  Producer ByteString m r
    ->  Producer ByteString m (Either SomeException (Producer ByteString m r))
streamImage p0 = do
    e0 <- lift (skipPrefix’ p0)
    case e0 of
        Left exc -> return (Left (toException exc))
        Right p1 -> do
            e1 <- decodeBase64 p1
            case e1 of
                Left exc -> return (Left exc)
                Right p2 -> do
                    e2 <- lift (skipSuffix’ p2)
                    case e2 of
                        Left exc -> return (Left (toException exc))
                        Right p3 -> return (Right p3)
```

In other words, `streamImage` would take a `Producer` as input that begins at the first character of the JSON record, and it will stream the decoded image bytes extracted from that record.  If decoding succeeds, then it will return the remainder of the byte stream immediately after the JSON record.